# Insert value into table without knowin column name

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to update values in table using column name from another table, why it is not working?

You can see that I have in table `TableOfDocuments`, in column `WORD1`, the name `DANA`.

Now I need to go to the other table where column name is `DANA` and add 1
this is my code:

```
 UPDATE BagOfWords
 SET (SELECT WORD1 FROM TableOfDocuments WHERE ID=1)=1
 WHERE USER_ID=1
```

with this code I'm getting the column name in the other table (Dana):

```
SELECT WORD1 FROM TableOfDocuments WHERE ID=1
```

BagOfWords Table

```
USER_ID|DANA|LOVES|EAT
----------------------
   1  |  0  |  0  |  0
```

TableOfDocuments Table

```
ID|WORD1|WORD2|WORD3
--------------------
1 | Dana| loves |pizza
```

So, after getting help is it possible to do something like this in order not to type WORD1---WORD5 separately? Obviously I tried but this doesn't work, what do I need to add or change in order to make this work?

```
 declare
      l_col varchar2(128);
    begin
      select word1,word2,word3,word4,word5 into l_col from TableOfDocuments WHERE ID=1;
      execute immediate 'UPDATE BagOfWords SET ' || l_col || ' = 1 WHERE USER_ID=1';
    end;
```

Comment: If you need to do such a thing, you need, in Oracle [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm), and in mySQL [Prepared Statements in SQL Scripts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Similar things for other databases. Standard SQL does not allow you to use the result of a SQL query in lieu of a `column name`.

Comment: There is no _easy_ way to decide dynamically which column name.  Sounds like a poorly designed schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that, you need dynamic SQL, and be careful with that. Below is a simple example (without any error handling, for educational purpose only).

```
declare
  l_col varchar2(128);
begin
  select word1 into l_col from TableOfDocuments WHERE ID=1;
  execute immediate 'UPDATE BagOfWords SET ' || l_col || ' = 1 WHERE USER_ID=1';
end;
/
```